# Exposing Relay Hybrid Connection using API Management or LB

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-api-management

is it possible to expose azure hybrid connection into public network using API management or Load Balancer?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a Webapp which supports [azure hybrid connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-hybrid-connections), to reach onto your on-premise. Then you can have WebApp as a backend to ApiManagement.

You can secure access to your WebApp, using Mutual Cert Authentication or Firewall only allowing ApiManagement static IP Address.